# Working with an ADF Database file

Tags: linux

Kind of an odd situation. I manage a `DL3000 Series door lock`. The software to manage the database for users is Windows Only(`dlwindows`), and kind of unwieldy to use... It stores it's information in an `.adf` File.

I'm assuming based on some research that it's an `ACT! Data File` Database... If I could sort out a way of interacting with it on one of my servers via command line, it would simplify my life immensely.

Does anyone have any familiarity with `.adf` files, or any other information that might be helpful? I've done some light searching, but can't seem to find much information on the file extension in general, other then what it might be.

Much appreciated

Comment: You’re trying to manipulate or search the adf file on a Linux system?

Comment: Basically, I want to be able to manipulate the database on a linux server, so I can write scripts to handle the entries, rather then having to use the windows GUI application.

Comment: would it not be simpler to the communication between the DL3000 and the dlwindows program, so you could re-implement as a linux tool with sane (i.e. text) files?  according to google, it's am RS-232 serial connection with an optional USB<-->RS-232 adaptor.

Comment: btw, with a USB to RS232 adaptor, reverse engineering is probably easier.  This is a good starting point: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2416/how-to-reverse-engineer-simple-usb-device-windows-linux

Comment: My concern is less with the connection to the the lock. That is simple enough, and yes, I use DLwindows for that. My problem is that for user management, adding users to a particular lock, removing users from a particular lock. DLwindows has a terrible cumbersome interface. If i could manipulate the database directly via command-line, preferably on the linux server that hosts my LDAP server, I could then very easily export/import the database back into DLwindows for the actual lock management part. But...I need a way to interact with the ADF file via linux for that to be a possibility

Comment: this might be useful https://serverfault.com/questions/77712/sqlserver-need-to-access-an-act-database-for-data-migration.  you'll be lucky to find many (any) people here with direct knowledge of .ADF files (Evan Anderson's answer is a good example of a typical unix persons attitude to proprietary lock-in file formats: we hate it, but we'll use it if we have to...and even then only for as long as it takes to extract the data and then kill it with fire).    also, asking about or searching for adf on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ might come up with something.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295192/extract-data-from-adf-file